# self-quenched oscillator

Tags: rf, oscillator, receiver, oscillation, cadence

[image: self-quenched]
 I am trying to simulate a circuit which is composed of an oscillator which oscillates and reaches a maximum oscillation amplitude, then there's a peak detector that is following the peak of oscillation in one output (Venv+ in the picture) and Venv- is the reference. the outputs of the peak detector circuit, (Venv+ and Venv-) are then applied to a comparator. and the output of comparator is applied to some inverting stages to produce some delay. then the output of a comparator stage is applied to the horizontal NMOS to quench the oscillations. an ook signal is injected to the oscillator. when the input signal exists, the oscillations start and decay faster and more quench signals are produced compared to when there is no injected signal.

[image: curves]

so far everything's fine! but i want to have this quenching mechanism by applying this quench pulses to the gate of the tail transistor. the problem is the amplitude of the oscillations don't reach the maximum, and actually the width of the pulse generated in the gate of the tail transistor is not much (about 2 nanoseconds). can anyone give me an idea about what i am doing wrong?? i could give more explanations .
[image: tail]
[image: tail_curves]

Comment: This smells a lot like an xy problem, perhaps you can say what problem your circuit is trying to solve, that could give you better answers

Comment: This is going to be a receiver actually, after the first comparator, i will have a low pass filter and another comparator which compares the average of the output of the first comparator with a reference and say if a "one" was sent or a "zero" (it would demodulate the injected ook signal to the oscillator).

Comment: and doing so, depends on the quenching pulses that i described more in the question. i want to do this quenching through the tail transistor. but the amplitude of the oscillation is a less than when the oscillations are decayed using that horizontal transistor in the first picture.